# Ordenar resultado de uma consulta com JOIN baseado no número de registros de uma das tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Supondo que eu tenha duas tabelas no meu banco de dados (`pedidos` e `pedidos_itens`) de que maneira posso obter os dados dos **pedidos** ordenados pelos pedidos que contém mais itens?

Já tentei fazer um *Right Join*, mas não sei o que usar na cláusula *order by*, já que meu objetivo é ordenar pelo número de registros da tabela `pedidos_itens`.

Comment: Como sabes quais os pedidos que contém mais itens? é um numero num dos campos de cada entrada ou a quantidade de entradas com um dado ID?

Comment: Cada linha da tabela `pedidos_itens` é um item, então teria que ordenar a consulta  pelo número de linhas da tabela `itens_pedidos`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(pi.*) AS itens,
  p.id AS id,
  p.descricao AS desc
FROM pedido p
  INNER JOIN pedido_itens pi ON
    pi.id_pedido = p.id
GROUP BY id, desc
ORDER BY itens ASC
```

A idéia é dar um `COUNT` da quantidade de itens retornados para o pedido, agrupar os dados do registro no `GROUP BY` e um `ORDER BY` pelo `COUNT`.